# Call a struct field with a string in golang

Tags: string, go, struct, reflection

I want to call a field of my structure with a string, so I checked out and I saw that I need to use the reflection package.
Here's my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)


type cmd struct{
    echo func() (string,error)
}



func main() {
    cmd:=cmd{
        echo : func () (string,error){
            return "test", nil
        },
    }
    fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(&cmd).MethodByName("echo").Call([]reflect.Value{}))

}
```

And when I want to build it, it panics like :

```
panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.Call on zero Value

goroutine 1 [running]:
reflect.flag.mustBe(...)
        c:/go/src/reflect/value.go:208
reflect.Value.Call(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc0000c7f50, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc000086058)
        c:/go/src/reflect/value.go:319 +0x174
```

I do not understand the `[]reflect.Value{}`, why do I need to use this on the line :

```
reflect.ValueOf(&cmd).MethodByName("echo").Call([]reflect.Value{})
```

Hope someone can help ! :D

Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cmd.echo` is not a method. It's a field of function type. Access it using `Value.FieldByName()`.

And only exported fields can be accessed, rename it to `Echo`.

And you have to pass a non-pointer `cmd`, or if you pass `&cmd`, you have to call `Value.Elem()`.

Working example:

```
type cmd struct {
    Echo func() (string, error)
}

cmd := cmd{
    Echo: func() (string, error) {
        return "test", nil
    },
}
fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(cmd).FieldByName("Echo").Call([]reflect.Value{}))
```

This outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/vpyX8mT0bL4)):

```
[test <error Value>]
```

Also note that if the function does not have parameters, you pass `nil` to `Value.Call()`:

```
reflect.ValueOf(cmd).FieldByName("Echo").Call(nil)
```

Comment: Thanks man ! And if I want to have a parameter in my function, do I pass this parameter in the {} of the reflect.Value or in the array of the Call ? Cuz I try to pass "test" for example and in the reflect.Value it says : cannot use "test" (type string) as type reflect.Value in slice literal. When I pass it in the array of Call, it says : invalid array bound "test". I don't understand how to pass a parameter like "test" for my function...

Comment: @Zouglou If the function has a `string` parameter, this is how you can call that: `reflect.ValueOf(cmd).FieldByName("Echo").Call([]reflect.Value{reflect.ValueOf("someparam")})`